# Can I remove this without a tall ladder?

Tags: electrical, lighting

We have an office room at the front of our home with tall sloped ceilings and of course, per Murphy’s law, it was one of the first lightbulbs to go out since we moved in.  Has anyone removed one of these light covers using a light changing pole? Or is my only option to get a tall ladder? I’d estimate it’s about 12 - 13’ and I have a shorter ladder that I could use in addition to the light changing pole.

[image: Ceiling Light Image]

Comment: Most light changing poles grip bare light bulbs.  You have to remove that cover first.  Do not use a ladder by yourself, have at least one or two helpers to hold the ladder(or phone 911).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that’s what I was afraid of… I’ve seen some have a suction cup type attachment, but not sure if it would work with this type of fixture… or if I’d have glass falling on my head. May just have to rent a taller ladder or invest in one, but we also have some recess ceiling lights that I thought might be able to be changed with a pole grip.

Comment: +1 for crip659. We've had fixtures like this. You have to unscrew the center metal-looking part, take the glass down, then unscrew the sideways-mounted bulbs. A light bulb wand won't handle any of these tasks. Ladder time...

Comment: Consider changing the whole light fixture while you're up there. Pick one you can easily change with your light bulb changing pole (light bulb wand). So next time you don't have to rent (or even drag out & set up) a ladder or scaffolding

Comment: If you don't want to own a taller stepladder, you can rent one from Home Depot for $23 for 4 hours.  If no HD, there may be another place nearby with rentals.  Of course, you gotta transport it...

Comment: @Xen2050 Or just change for a fixture with integrated LEDs, which are cooled properly and so less likely to fail (unlike bulbs in a fixture intended for incandescents). Then you'll only have to do this once a decade (or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going to happen with a suction cup bulb changer. *If* you were able to get it to grab the little nipple screw at the center, once you got it unscrewed, the glass globe would fall.

You'll need a ladder, or, you can buy/rent lightweight scaffolding that should easily get you that high.

If there are several high ceilings in the house, you might consider it more economical to buy some lightweight scaffold for changing lights, painting, other general maintenance tasks. It would probably be cheaper in the long-run than it would be to rent it each time you need to do something like this.

Oh, Pro-Tip™: While you're up there, go ahead and change *both* bulbs. Odds are good that they were installed at roughly the same time, so since one's failed, the other's likely ready to go soon, too. Use the still functioning bulb in a fixture where changing the bulb requires nothing more than standing on a chair.

When I install LED bulbs (especially inside a fixture), I use a fine-point Sharpie™ (or similar) to date the base of the bulb so I've got an idea of how long they're lasting. You could mark the "used" bulb so you know that it might not have a "full" life left when you replace another burnt out bulb elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect to be able to safely remove and replace that cover with a light-changing pole.

Looking at typical ladders.

- 6' - max. standing height 3'10"

I don't think that will be enough.

- 8' - max. standing height 5'9". Also says "reach height" 12'.

I think that should be enough. 5'9" + 5'6" (average US adult) = 11'3". Which, to me, should mean a reach height a little above 12'.

Factors to consider:

- Your height (or height of tallest able-bodied person in your household).
- Height you need to reach.
- What you need to do. Removing and replacing a light cover and light bulb *should* be a bit easier than, for example, replacing a light fixture.

An 8' ladder should be easy enough to store in the basement or a shed. And you will find many uses for it in the future.

Comment: A bucket/bag to hold parts when you are up there would be handy also.  Should keep one hand free to hold/grap on the ladder if possible.

Comment: A hoodie sweatshirt with a pouch is a good place for the bulbs and the bolt holding the dome on. A spare pair of hands is good for holding the dome, even if it's an extra trip or two up/down the ladder...

Comment: A 'ladder bucket' that attaches to the 8' ladder you get would be very helpful. Thanks to your question, I found a Werner one at Lowes I gotta have. Not sure how it connects but will find out. :)